# Python 3 - Match items with same index from multiple lists

Tags: list, python-3.x, match

I have two lists with items such as:

```
oldNamesList = ["A.txt", "B.txt", "a a.txt"]
newNamesList = ["a.txt", "b.txt", "a_a.txt"]
```

I don’t know how many items there are (they change according to input of script), the only thing I know is that there is always an item in newNamesList for an item in oldNamesList, and an item in oldNamesList for an item in newNamesList.

So, what I want is automatically match the item in the first list with the one with same index in the second:

```
print(oldNamesList[0], ">", newNamesList[0])
print(oldNamesList[1], ">", newNamesList[1])
```

... and so on.

Googling the question led only to ways to match a given value: i.e., find items common to both lists, or find "rock" in list1 and delete the item with same index in list2.

From other questions I found itertools (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools), in particular itertools.products: but if I do something like:

```
combined = itertools.product(oldNamesList, newNamesList)
combined = list(combined)
```

I get a permutation (or something like that):

```
[('A.txt', 'a.txt'), ('A.txt', 'b.txt'), ('A.txt', 'a_a.txt'), ('B.txt', 'a.txt'), ('B.txt', 'b.txt'), ('B.txt', 'a_a.txt'), ('a a.txt', 'a.txt'), ('a a.txt', 'b.txt'), ('a a.txt', 'a_a.txt')]
```

So I think it’s not the right tool here.

Comment: Are you looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)?

Comment: Aah, it was as simple as:     for a, b in zip(oldNamesList, newNamesList):
        print(a, ">", b) ... thank’you again @jonrsharpe !!!